# add value to existing javascript code on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a javascript widget that will display a data chart.. and i have an dropdown box which gives the user the ability to change the theme. so when the user selects a theme it should change and show the user the new theme.

Widget code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new TradingView.widget({
  "width": 500,
  "height": 400,
  "interval": "1",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "White",
  "style": "2",

}); 
</script>
```

HTML/JS code

```
<select>
    <option value="moonlight">Moon</option>
    <option value="darkness">Dark</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).on('change','.theme',function(){
      alert(this.value);
    });
</script>
```

How do i get add the `this.value` to the widget JS code `theme` parameter?

Comment: Are you using any js plugin?

Comment: @deepakb Looks like jQuery and is tagged with `jQuery`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should put the new widget code in a function and access the `theme` from the args:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function themeChanger(theme){
  var themeWidget = new TradingView.widget({
    "width": 500,
    "height": 400,
    "interval": "1",
    "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
    "theme": theme,
    "style": "2",

  }); 
  return themeWidget;
}

$(document).on('change','.theme',function(){
   var widget = themeChanger(this.value);
   // do something with widget.
});

</script>
```

Comment: just got one small question..i added the same to different widget but when i choose an option from the dropdown, the widget loads like in a blank page and the dropdown is not visible. http://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/3e9jaLku/5/ can u please have a look at that fiddle and tell me what am i doing wrong there?

Comment: It seems it is replacing everything in the body with the widget.

Answer (score 0):

you can use global variable

```js
var chartParams={
  "width": 500,
  "height": 400,
  "interval": "1",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "White",
  "style": "2",

}
new TradingView.widget(chartParams);
$(document).on('change','.theme',function(){
     chartParams["theme"]=this.value
     new TradingView.widget(chartParams);
    });
```